# SessionStorage and reloading page javascript

Tags: javascript, time, session-storage

I'm trying to keep information (timer) in sessionStorage key.
I would like to keep timer runing if user reload the page.

I tried something like this

```
    var timer = 50;
    sessionStorage.setItem('timer_station', timer);
    var timer_data = sessionStorage.getItem('timer_station');
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        timer_data--;
        console.log(timer_data);
        $('#count-timer').text(timer_data);
        if (timer_data === 0) {
            $('#count-timer').text('Désolé, votre réservation a expirée');
            clearInterval(interval);
            sessionStorage.clear();
        }
    }, 1000);
},
```

But when i'm reloading the page, timer reset.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Is that all your relevant code?  Your braces don't match up.  If it is, the answer is simple - you're resetting it in your first two lines of code you've posted.

Comment: You never *set* a value. Try `sessionStorage.setItem('timer_station', timer_data)`

Comment: Nah sorry, i'm using a function in OOP. There is timer: function() {} before

Comment: Also, you probably want to removeItem() when complete, not clear().

Answer (score 2):

Firstly we need to handle the case that they haven't been here before:

```
var timer = sessionStorage.getItem('timer_station');
if (!timer){
    timer = 50
}
```

Then do our interval, saving the new time left as we go:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    timer--;
    console.log(timer);
    sessionStorage.setItem('timer_station', timer);
    $('#count-timer').text(timer);
    if (timer === 0) {
        $('#count-timer').text('Désolé, votre réservation a expirée');
        clearInterval(interval);
        sessionStorage.clear();
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're setting the timer_station value on each reload. You want to move the setItem into an if check. Something like...

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
if (isThereATimerStationAlreadySetCheck) {
  //do stuff with it
} else {
  //set it
}

}, 1000);
```